# Interpreter with installed 'matplotlib': ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

Tags: python, matplotlib, conda

I use JetBrains DataSpell for Jupyter. I use conda interpreter (Python 3.10) and I have installed matplotlib, but when I run this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I got this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

The strangest thing is that when I start writing "import matpl..." my kernel prompts me "matplotlib" and see class "pyplot" also. So my kernel sees this library while writing code...
I got installed matplotlib 3.5.2 version
[installed package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuNa3.png)

Comment: 1. try to uninstall and re-install.  2. make sure it is installed on the same version of python.  ie. you have `3.10`, but was it installed on `3.9` ?

Comment: 1. I tried several times.
2. I think it is - I use Python 3.10 and during installation I don't change anything

Comment: Have you tried **inside a cell in the notebook**, running `%pip install matplotlib`? Or if you are using conda, try running `%conda install matplotlib` inside a cell in the notebook.